# 2^(-x)=realmin in Matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

I tried to find the largest value x for which 2^(-x) = realmin in Matlab by the expression -log2(realmin). The result is 1022. However, when I try the code 2^(-x) > 0 for x ranging from 1023 up to 1074, the result is 1(True). From my understanding, realmin is the smallest positive floating-point number. So what is the reason that -log2(realmin) does not give the largest x such that 2^(-x) > 0?

Comment: I don't know MatLab, but I guess it is the smallest positive **normalized** FP number. Denormals (less precise) can be smaller. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in previous comment, realmin function returns the smallest normalized number. You can go as far as 2^(-1075) while using denormalized numbers, as I found out using the following very simple script:

```
%% Script to check the smallest possible power of two in Matlab 

power = 0;

while 2^power > 0
    power = power - 1;
end

sprintf('%d', power)
```

That's your first option. You could also use `eps(0)` to get the smallest denormalized number in Matlab, and you would get:

```
Trial>> log2(eps(0))

ans =

       -1074
```

Which is correct.

You should read the Wikipedia page on denormalized/normalized numbers for further information.